# Parent/Child pages

Tags: theme-development, menus, pages, wp-list-pages

I find that the parent/child pages in the "Pages" area of WordPress has become a bit confusing since the introduction of the new menu creation area.

Using the new menu system, as far as I know I can set a page which is actually itself a child page (in the pages section) to be a parent of a page which is actually itself a parent.

Can someone tell me, is the whole parent/child pages scenario now superseded by the new menu system, and unless we plan on using wp_list_pages in the theme should we avoid having child pages altogether and instead just decide where they go in the menu area. What is normaly done on a site that doesn't use wp_list_pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using the new menu system, as far as I know I can set a page which is
>   actually itself a child page (in the pages section) to be a parent of
>   a page which is actually itself a parent=
>   **TRUE**
>
> **What is normaly done on a site that doesn't use wp_list_pages?**
>   I can't speak for all, but I do just as you mentioned. I order the menu myself. If you don't need to manually arrange your sites menu and you find the wp_nav confusing you're probably better off using `wp_list_pages` for you menu, and using the page order in the Edit Pages screen to control your menu order.

Comment: thanks Jeremy, so would you think it would be fair to say it's generally better to use one system or the other ..... (unless maybe for instance the theme is using a combination of custom menus and wp_list_pages) .... rather than trying to replicate the custom menu arrangement in the pages section.

Comment: It really depends on who's using the website. If it's a site I'm building for me, I always use the wp_nav menu's. If I'm building a site for a client that intends on adding content themselves, I explain the options and let them choose. For the clients that are technically challenged I use wp_list pages since it's the easiest to explain.

Comment: Yes I suppose it does - i'm doing documentation for clients who just want it to work in the most straightforward way; and in this case I think that's going to avoid parent/child pages and just let them do sub pages in the menus. Thanks for your help, I was just unsure if setting a page to a child had any other bearing other than menu position.